# elmah - an item with the same key is already exist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah, .net-framework-version

I have one project in asp.net mvc in .Net Framework 4.5 and MVC 4.

I was installed elmah before some months ago and now I am trying to update the elmah but it is not showing me any update button so I removed all the elmah related things from my code but now when I try to install from nuget it gives me the error.

**an item with the same key is already exist**

Error page:
[image]

Comment: Did you uninstall the package correctly ?

Comment: delete all package in  package folder and than try

Comment: @ISHIDA I tried all the way to uninstall and install

Comment: @Jay I have so many packages dear it's not feasible for me right now takes very long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all show your **package.config** file if any packages have two times referenced or not than try to uninstall or install any new packages or existing packages.

Sometime after checking and changing in package.config file need restart of your visual studio so do it once and than check if it is working or not.

Comment: Ohhhh come on again sir you helped me so helpful. Yes I have two entries of  webpages and razor in packages.config I removed one and than restart and install it it is running now.

Comment: It is not necessary that the dll you are trying to install is already available, may be there are some other existing files have twice entries so try to check existing and than try new one.